# If $A,B\in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ are similar, does it imply that $\det(A+3I)=\det(B+3I)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

If $A,B\in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ are similar, does it imply that
$\det(A+3I)=\det(B+3I)$?
If so, why? I know that $\det(A)=\det(B)$.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose $PAP^{-1}=B$. Then $P(A+3I)P^{-1}=PAP^{-1}+3PIP^{-1}=B+3I$.